# Customizing images in HTML

Tags: html, image

I need to make a website which allows you to buy customized shoes.
One of the feature is that you see a page with a pair of shoes, then you can select
'stickers' to put on the shoes, and the color of those stickers.
These can be selected from a panel aside of the shoes.

I was thinking of a way on how to do this,
My idea:
Display an image of the pair of shoes, on
that image I place two small img-tags (which represent
the stickers), when the user clicks on a kind of sticker I fill the img-tag
with that sticker. When the user selects a colour, I replace the image in img-tag
with a sticker-image having the selected color.

But this would need absolute positioning (not responsive?) and a lot of image-combinations
(all stickers having all colors)...

So, what would be the best way to do it?
I don't think there is a kind of plugin-thing for this?

Comment: You should be able to find something useful here: https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CAFA_enNL684NL684&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=customizing+clothes+plugin&*

Answer (score 0):

You can make absolute position responsive by using percents or vh/vw, altho you could use canvas to render your shoes and stickers in a single tag.

And for colouring of stickers its possible to use SVG. You can change SVG colour width JavaScript without any other uploads. But for complicated images it's not very useful.